# How can I calculate, How much time is left before tomorrow?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, simpledateformat

How can I calculate and format time like HH:mm, Of much time is left before tomorrow? with SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: don't use `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date`, `Calendar` - these classes were replaces by classes in the `java.time` package (and sub-packages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SimpleDateFormat` and related legacy classes were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Determining “tomorrow” requires a time zone. Days start earlier as you move eastward through time zones.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
```

Capture the current moment as seen through that time zone.

```
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

Now we are in a position to determine “tomorrow”, specifically the first moment of the following day.

Extract the date portion.

```
LocalDate today = now.toLocalDate() ;
LocalDate tomorrow = today.plus( 1 ) ;
```

Get first moment. Note that we do *not* assume the day starts at 00:00 . Some dates in some zones start at a different time of day, such as 01:00 . Let *java.time* determine the first moment.

```
ZonedDateTime startTomorrowTokyo = tomorrow.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

Calculate time to elapse.

```
Duration untilTomorrow = Duration.between ( now , startTomorrowTokyo ) ;
```

Generate text in standard ISO 8601 format.

```
String output = untilTomorrow.toString() ;
```

If you insist on the risky ambiguous use of clock-time to represent the duration, you can build your own string by interrogating the `Duration` object. Call its `to…Part` methods.

Answer (score 1):

```java
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.Duration;


LocalDateTime tomorrowMidnight = LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.now(), LocalTime.MIDNIGHT).plusDays(1);        
        
Duration duration = Duration.between(LocalDateTime.now(), tomorrowMidnight);
System.out.printf("%d:%d", duration.toHours(), duration.toMinutes()%60);
```

Comment: `LocalDateTime` is exactly the wrong class to use here. That class cannot represent a moment (a specific point on the timeline) because it purposely lacks the context of a time zone or offset from UTC.

Comment: Another problem here is to assume a day starts at 00:00. That is not always the case. Politicians can decide the day starts at any time they say. And some have said 01:00, for example.